# Displaying a single output for a false result in a foreach loop with string array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach

I apologize if this has been answered I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for or concisely put it into a single sentence to search. I've almost solved it myself but can't figure this out. I am new to programming so this is probably an easy answer for someone.

I have a string array in which a person can give an input letter, and find all the strings which contain this letter and display them. Which I acheived using a foreach loop.

The problem I am facing is if there are no matches, I only want it to output a single "No Match" string instead of replacing each string that doesn't match.

Here is the chunk of code in question:

```
           string letter = Console.ReadLine();
           
           string no = "No match";
        
           foreach(string x in words) 
           {
             if(x.Contains(letter))
             {
              Console.WriteLine(x);
             }
             else {
                 Console.WriteLine(no);
             }
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `bool` to keep track of whether a match was found:

```
string letter = Console.ReadLine();
   
string no = "No match";

bool foundMatch = false;

foreach(string x in words) 
{
    if(x.Contains(letter))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        foundMatch = true;
    }
} 

if(!foundMatch)
{
    Console.WriteLine(no);
}
```

Comment: `foundMatch = true; break;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of outputting to the console within the loop, consider separating the code that performs the logic from the code that interacts with the user.... i.e., put the `Console.WriteLine` afterward.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetMatches(string[] words, string letter)
{
    foreach(string x in words) 
    {
        if(x.Contains(letter)) yield return x;
    }
}

//Main program
string letter = Console.ReadLine();
var matches = GetMatches(words, letter).ToList();
if (matches.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No match.");
}
else
{
    foreach (var match in matches) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
}
```